# Android Augmented Reality (AR) Concept

Tags: android

I am new to Augmented Reality in android.

If any one knows some AR concepts, please help me.

Comment: have you tried googling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good library for AR - [ARToolKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARToolKit) . There is also a port for Android - [AndAr](http://code.google.com/p/andar/)